# must any $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_G(V, L^2(G))$ be continuous?

Tags: representation-theory, lp-spaces, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact group and $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space with a continuous $G$-action. Consider a linear map $\phi: V \to L^2(G)$ satisfying that for any $v \in V, h \in G$:

$$
    \phi(v)(g h) = \phi(h \cdot v)(g) \quad \text{for almost all $g \in G$}
$$
Must every such $\phi$ be continuous?

In my representation theory course we used this fact to conclude that matrix coefficients give rise to an isomorphism $V^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_G(V, L^2(G))$ and ultimately prove the Peter-Weyl theorem.

**EDIT:** This wasn't the question I was meaning to ask, so I asked the right question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864743/must-any-phi-in-operatornamehom-gv-l2g-have-continuous-images?noredirect=1#comment7971607_3864743).

Answer (score 2):

A linear map from a finite-dimensional normed vector space is always continuous. The $G$-equivariance plays no role here.

Comment: I noticed that I worded my question wrong. I didn't mean to ask about the continuity of $\phi$, but whether the images of $\phi$ are continuous functions on $G$.